# Can a Waterfall Chart be Dynamically Resized?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have an issue where I am trying to dynamically resize and update a waterfall graph in Excel 2016. Using the `offset()` formula, I'm trying to automatically make the graphs resize. The issue is that I cannot make my waterfall graph resize, but I can make a bar graph resize using the same formulas.

First, I define my named regions as follows:

mode = `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100),1)`
x = `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100),1)`

So for example, I have both graphs and my data like this:

[image]

Then, when I add a new set of data "d", my bar graph updates, but my waterfall graph does not.

[image]

Could anybody explain why this might be the case and suggest a solution? I want my waterfall graph to include the new "d" data, as well. I'm happy to provide any more clarification, if necessary.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: The images are blocked by the corporate firewall - please use a friendly hosting service like the one offered here (at least it WAS friendly...)